# To prove given category is abelian category

Tags: category-theory, definition, abelian-categories

In my text book, to prove given category is abelian category,
author just checks there exists Ker and Coker.

In general, we omit other axioms to check(and existence of Ker and Coker is most difficult?)

Do we often omit checking other axioms(additive category, coimf→imf is isom is difficult)?

I'm not familiar with category theory, thank you for your comments.

Comment: That's not a complete proof without more details. Additivity is usually easy, the interesting axiom to check in general is that $\text{coim} \to \text{im}$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thank you for your comment. I will try hard to prove check 'coim→I'm axiom, thank you !

Comment: To check that an additive subcategory of an abelian category is itself abelian, you do just have to check that it is closed under kernels and cokernels, as then the $\text{coim} \to \text{im}$ axiom is automatically true. Maybe that is what your book is doing?

Comment: Oh, thank you, that's it. My book is checking etale (φ,Γ)module is abelian. But this is subcategory of modules over π-adic completion of Laurent power series, which is abelian category.

Comment: Could you give me some reference about your comment? (especially, 'coim→Im axiom follows from other axioms in the case of subcategory of abelian category' )

Comment: I meant to write *full* additive subcategory, sorry. I don't offhand know a reference, but it's very easy, since if $\mathcal{S}$ is a full additive subcategory of an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ that is closed under kernels and cokernels, then for a map $f$ of $\mathcal{S}$, the map $\text{coim}f\to\text{im}f$ is the same whether you construct it in $\mathcal{S}$ or in $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: I think one should emphasize that a full subcategory $\mathscr{A}\subseteq\mathscr{B}$ of a (co)complete category $\mathscr{B}$ is closed under (co)limits, if given a diagram in $\mathscr{A}$ the (co)limit computed in $\mathscr{B}$ is an object in $\mathscr{A}$. This is **not** the same as saying that $\mathscr{A}$ has (co)limits. In the latter case (co)limits in $\mathscr{A}$ have nothing to do with those in $\mathscr{B}$ in particular we would **not** be able to deduce the $\operatorname{coim}\rightarrow\operatorname{im}$ axiom of $\mathscr{A}$ from that of $\mathscr{B}$.

Comment: @JonasLinssen That's true. The result I'm stating here uses the stronger fact that the subcategory is **closed** under (co)kernels in the larger category, not just that it **has** (co)kernels. I suspect that was what the OP's source was using.